# An unexpected JAVA error while starting tomcat on SunOS

Tags: java, tomcat5.5

HI i am getting below error while starting tomcat in SUNOS.

```
#
# An unexpected error has been detected by HotSpot Virtual Machine:
#
#  SIGBUS (0xa) at pc=0xf904c150, pid=29348, tid=1
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (1.5.0_11-b03 mixed mode)
# Problematic frame:
# J  java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine()I
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as hs_err_pid29348.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

**Apache Tomcat : apache-tomcat-5.5.26**

**JAVA : 1.5.0_11**

Can any one tell me what this error is ?.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this machine using ECC memory?

Comment: @chrylis : Sorry but how do i know if my machine uses ECC memory?